# Restarting a Select loop with new variables in bash

Tags: bash, unix, select, loops

I'm trying to restart the select loop after I change the variables inside of it, currently it increments everything, but it does not rerun the select loop. Here is my code:

```
select listfile in "${FILEARRAY[@]:$START:$FINISH}" Next
do
    if [[ $listfile == "Next" ]];then
        echo "Check point 1 $START and $FINISH"
        if [[ ${#FILEARRAY[@]} > $FINISH ]];then
            START=$(($START + 23))
            FINISH=$(($FINISH + 23))
            echo "Check point 2 $START and $FINISH"
        elif [[ ${#FILEARRAY[@]} < $FINISH || ${#FILEARRAY[@]} == $FINISH ]];then
            echo "No more files"
            exit
        fi
    else
        FILE=$listfile
        break
    fi
done
```

I edited in check point 1 and 2, check point 1 gives me 0 and 23 (like it should) and check point 2 give me 23 and 46 (also like it should). After it increments I want it to restart the select but using position 23 through 46 from the array.

Edit 2: The array just contains names of files:

```
FILEARRAY=( $(ls) )
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish here (and in your previous post). Please edit your post to show a simple example of what you want this to look like, i.e. Step 1, use select to display N files (looks like .....), Step 2 modify select values (I really don't think this is possible!), Step 3 use select to display N+1 -> N+6 files (looks like .....). Step 4? In anycase we only need to see 2-3 lines of output for each segment. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I've added some more information, does that help clarify what exactly I'm trying to do?

Comment: so you're trying to add a paging facilty for select?

Comment: @shellter yes, the terminology was escaping me

Comment: if you'd use the shell debugging facility (`set -vx` above the code you want to debug), you would see that the shell reads all of the code between the `select` and the `done`, making it impossible to modify select stuff while the shell is processing that block of code. What you may be able to do, is to maintain your $FILEARRAY externally and then have 2 blocks of select code, changing the values of FILEARRAY before you get to the 2nd select. The numbers in select won't increment but you'll be controlling the output for your user so they don't have to scroll back on the screen. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I got it to work, I added a while loop outside of the select loop. It might have been unconventional but it works like I need it to, takes for your help

Comment: Darn, I was just about to suggest that, once I really understood how/what your `"${FILEARRAY[@]:$START:$FINISH}"` is supposed to work. Good trick! Be sure to post your answer so you can accept it later, and gain rep points. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question either, but according to your comments I "think" I know what you're trying to do but still I've no idea WHY you would do that.

in any case let me explain you a few things, first of all the `select` isn't getting a variable per se, what it gets is the expanded result because the shell replaces that before the command sees it so, if you want to perform different `select` on each slice you need to loop from the outside and rerun the select statement with the new arguments every time.

I would do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pagesize=23

filearray=(*)
start=0
while true; do
    pagefiles=("${filearray[@]:$start:$pagesize}")
    ((start > 0)) && pagefiles=(Prev "${pagefiles[@]}")
    ((start+pagesize < ${#filearray[@]})) && pagefiles=("${pagefiles[@]}" Next)
    select listfile in "${pagefiles[@]}"; do
        case $listfile in
        Prev)
            start=$((start-pagesize));;
        Next)
            start=$((start+pagesize));;
        *)
            filename=$listfile
        esac
        break
    done
    [[ $filename ]] && break
done

echo "$filename"
```

notice the array slice notation in bash doesn't take start-end it takes start-length.

also, and this is VERY important, don't EVER parse or reuse the output of `ls` (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) if you want all the files in the directory on an array just do `FILEARRAY=(*)` and it'll be safely stored.

Comment: it'll fail if there's files named either "Prev" or "Next" maybe we could add a check for that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
   STEP=23
   START=0
   FINISH=$STEP
   FILEARRAY=( $(ls) )


   function slct {
       START=$1
       STEP=$2
       FINISH=$3


       select listfile in "${FILEARRAY[@]:$START:$STEP}" Next
       do
           if [[ $listfile == "Next" ]];then
               echo "Check point 1 $START and $FINISH"
               if [[ ${#FILEARRAY[@]} -gt $FINISH ]];then
               echo ${#FILEARRAY[@]}   FA
               echo $FINISH FIN
                   START=$((START + STEP))
                   FINISH=$((FINISH + STEP))
                   slct $START $STEP $FINISH
                   break;
               echo "Check point 2 $START and $FINISH"

               elif [[ ${#FILEARRAY[@]} < $FINISH || ${#FILEARRAY[@]} == $FINISH ]];then
                   echo "No more files"
                   exit
               fi
           else
               FILE=$listfile
               echo SELECTED $listfile
               break
           fi
       done
   }

   slct 0 $STEP $STEP
```